# Strange behavior: T-sql char/string concatenation char

Tags: string, t-sql, string-concatenation

I have a strange behavior in t-sql. Giving the following test

```
   DECLARE @a char(22) = 'John went to buy a car', @b char(15)= 'Tom went to pub';  
   SELECT IIF(1=1 , @a, @b )+'. He met a friend';
```

Output ok:
       John went to buy a car. He met a friend.

```
   SELECT IIF(1=2 , @a, @b )+'. He met a friend';
```

Output wrong:

```
    Tom went to pub       . He met a friend.
```

The concatenation of variable char allocates 22 chars if test is true, and 22 chars otherwise! Thus in char concatenation through IIF (but the same happens with CASE) the output is allocated for the first expression (@b variable is considered as 22 chars!) Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An `IIF` is an **expression** and therefore needs a **data type**. This data type *can't* depend on what happens at execution time - it needs to be known at query compilation time.

Therefore, given that the two inputs are a `char(22)` and a `char(15)`, the data type picked by T-SQL for the *expression as a whole* is the 'wider' of these two, the more inclusive - namely, `char(22)`.

So whatever the execution-time result, the *type* of the result will be `char(22)`. Which, as you have observed, means that sometimes the result is space-padded compared to the chosen input.

---

Interestingly, I can't actually find this behaviour explicitly called out anywhere in [the documentation for `IIF`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/logical-functions-iif-transact-sql). It says there

> Returns the data type with the highest precedence from the types in true_value and false_value. For more information, see [Data Type Precedence (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-precedence-transact-sql)

*but* the [linked page on Precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-precedence-transact-sql) *doesn't* actually call out what happens for fixed-length character types such as `char` and `varchar`, unless I've missed it.

Comment: Thanks! It´s a great answer.